# Forwarding IPv4 to IPv6 in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, ipv6, ipv4, forwarding

I am trying to forward IPv4 traffic to IPv6. I currently have two Ubuntu boxes, and I am trying to use socat and SSH dynamic port forwarding to accomplish IPv4 to IPv6 forwarding, but no luck so far.

On my local system, I am doing a local port forwarding session to forward all traffic from localhost:9000 to localhost:5000 on server 1 using the following command.

```
ssh -f -N -L 9000:localhost:5000 root@<server 1>
```

On server 1, I am running the following socat command. The idea here is to forward all incoming IPv4 traffic on port 5000 to IPv6 on port 4444 on the localhost.

```
socat -d  TCP4-LISTEN:5000,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[::1]:4444
```

From there, I have an SSH IPv6 dynamic port forwarding session to forward all IPv6 traffic from server 1 to server 2, as shown in the following command.

```
ssh -6 -f -N -D 4444 root@<IPv6 addr of server 2>
```

When I attempt to proxy say web traffic via proxychains curl on my local system, I get "couldn't connect to server". Is there something wrong with my setup? Also, is there a more efficient way to do this without having to spin up two servers?

Comment: Does the local machine have direct access to server 2?